# Is there a way to make equals (==) check on kotlin.js.Date object work?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, assertion, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I would like to ask for some help/suggestions on an issue we're facing when trying to unit test platform specific `Date` classes in our Kotlin Multiplatform project.

Our Kotlin Multiplatform library targets; **JVM**, **Native** & **JavaScript** and is using the platform specific Date classes:

- java.util.Date (JVM)
- platform.Foundation.NSDate (Native)
- kotlin.js.Date (JS)

Which are exposed via an expected/actual `Date` class and used in public domain classes in the common package. For example:

```
public data class Event {
    val id: String,
    val start: Date
}
```

Long story short; when unit testing we found that assertEquals works for JVM & Native, but fails for JavaScript. For example:

```
import kotlin.js.Date
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class DateEqualsTest {

    @Test
    // Fails!
    fun dateEquals() {
        val first = Date(1_630_399_506_000)
        val second = Date(1_630_399_506_000)
        assertEquals(first, second)
    }

    @Test
    // Succeeds
    fun timestampEquals() {
        val first = Date(1_630_399_506_000)
        val second = Date(1_630_399_506_000)
        assertEquals(first.getTime(), second.getTime())
    }
}
```

The `assertEquals` fails for JS due to (I guess) a missing equals() operator in the kotlin.js.Date class.

Any suggestions on how to make the `assertEquals` work on all platforms given our use case? I can imagine a workaround could be to introduce a `DateWrapper` class that wraps the `Date` class and implement the equals() manually... but that would require use to refactor our public API and not sure if that is the best way to go. So any help/ suggestion is super welcome. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assertEquals` will not work because there is no way you can add `equals` method to `kotlin.js.Date` class - it is [external](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-interop.html#external-modifier) function exposing [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and all comparisons will be done the same way as would be done in JS

Just read this article:

- [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

To make it work you should use `getTime()` or provide wrapper class as you wrote **or** create overloaded assertEquals method in your test class or another util file

```
fun assertEquals(d1: Date, d2: Date) {
    kotlin.test.assertEquals(d1.getTime(), d2.getTime())
}
```

still then you need to take care about imports

Comment: Overloading the assertEquals method as an option; nice. Thanks for the added suggestion & explanation!